# Using find to find children of selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="container>
    <a href=""></a>
</div>
```

How can I use find to get the anchor? I've tried:

```
html = $(html);
html.find('.container a').attr('href', 'xyz');
```

With no luck.

FYI html var is a block of returned HTML from an ajax call.

Comment: `$('.container a').attr('href', 'xyz')` this should be ok

Comment: guradio - that wont work, it'll look on the page not my html var.

Comment: you didnt mention about the var

Comment: Always create jsfiddle about your problem, you dont have to return through ajax call , do it fixed as variable , so we can see  what you are doing wrong.

Comment: You are missing `"` from `<div class="container>`

Answer (score 1):

It woked

```
$( html ).children( ".container a" ).attr( 'href', 'xyz' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You html variable is itself having the container class. So, no need to find it again. You can just use,

```
html = $(html);
html.find('a').attr('href','xyz');
```

Hope this should work!!

Comment: if there are other a that is not in container what will happened?

Comment: Then it will select all the a links and apply the href. If you want select particularly one you can use a seperate class for it or you can select it by index. For ex, html.find('a:eq(1)').attr('href','xyz')

Comment: If the a element is not at all in the container it wont select that. It will only select the a tags in  the container class